# how to access HttpContext.Current.Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i have problem accessing  HttpContext.Current.Application From global.asax its seems to be null every time i try to access it. 
How can i to this?

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
HttpContext.Current.Application["Actions"] = "hello";
HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Global.asax, you're not in an actual request, so there's no current request nor context you can go by.  However, the Global class is a subclass of HttpApplication, so just use 'this', like:

```
this["Actions"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

To get the HttpApplication  object for the current HTTP request, use ApplicationInstance. (ASP.NET uses ApplicationInstance  instead of Application as a property name to refer to the current HttpApplication  instance in order to avoid confusion between ASP.NET and classic ASP. In classic ASP, Application refers to the global application state dictionary.)

Comment: Sorry, so if i want to access HttpContext.Current.Application["Actions"] how must i write it

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on access to the Application instance object in your web.config file like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Be sure to include a reference to System.Web.